# How to format Decimal in Asp.Net Mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to validate my editor field for entering the price of product like he can enter integer as 100,or after decimal only allows two digits as 85.12,and if user enters 85,12 also it is valid and it stores in database as 85.12.
model class:

```
[Required]

[LocalizedDisplayName("PRICE_PER_COLLI", NameResourceType = typeof(Strings))] [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

public decimal ColliPrice { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.ColliPrice) %> 
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ColliPrice)
```

Comment: `<%:` isn't MVC 3 format? Don't you mean MVC2??

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before like:

```
@Html.TextBox("ColliPrice", Model.ColliPrice.ToString("0.00")) 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ColliPrice)
```